# Updating Different Rows Quickly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which goes somewhat as follows:

Name1 (Key)|Name2(Key)|Total|LastUpdate

There will be hundreds of thousands of such records.

Now very frequently, my main program will query a source to get updated values. It will then update the total and last update. It may have to update hundreds of such rows.

Currently I have this:

```
Update mytable SET Total=[...] AND LastUpdate=[....] WHERE Name1='x' AND Name2='y';
Update mytable SET .....
```

I'm wondering if there is a faster way of updating the rows (similar to how you can Insert multiple rows at the same time).

The Totals will be completely different, but the LastUpdate time will be the same for each Update.

**Update to Clarify:**

The changes to total aren't just an increment, and don't depend on the current value - so its not deterministic in that regard. The source provides me a new value every second or so, and I have to put in a new one.

Comment: With single row updates the following all add up to quite significant overheads; sending the query over the network, the server parsing the query, and the server generating the execution plan. Assuming that you have appropriate indexes, the actual update is probably quite quick. You can mitigate much of the initial over-heads by using prepared statements (then keeping and re-using that connection and prepared statement). Transmitting the query becomes much smaller, the statement only needs parsing once, and the execution plan only needs generating once. Are you using prepared statements?

Comment: Using prepared statements made it work faster. Thanks for that advice.

Answer (score 0):

if its to slow to do the updates separatly, mayby you can do somthing like this

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_updates
(
  Name1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Name2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  total_increase INT NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY(Name1, Name2)
)

INSERT INTO mytable_updates VALUES ('x', 'y', 5), ('x', 'z', 3);
...

UPDATE mytable_updates 
LEFT JOIN mytable USING (Name1, Name2)
SET
  Total = Total + total_increase,
  LastUpdate = NOW();
```